# extjs spring 404 the requested resource is not available

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs

i am woking on extjs spring demo project .when i click on submit button is gives me 404 the requested resource not availabe.i am new to both extjs and spring .how to solve this issue.

this is my index.jsp

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
            Ext.QuickTips.init();
var login = new Ext.FormPanel({ 
items:[{ 
            fieldLabel:'Name', 
            name:'Name', 
            allowBlank:false 
        },{ 
            fieldLabel:'age', 
            name:'age', 
            allowBlank:false 
        },{ 
            fieldLabel:'id', 
            name:'id', 
            allowBlank:false 
        }],
 buttons:[{ 
            text:'Submit',
            formBind: true,  
            // Function that fires when user clicks the button 
            handler:function(){ 
             login.getForm().submit({ 
                    method:'POST',
                    url: 'HelloWeb/addStudent.htm' ,
                    //url: '/HelloWeb/addStudent.htm' ,
                    //action:'HelloWeb/addStudent.htm',
          }); 
            } 
        }] 
});
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)

public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("SpringWeb")Student student, 
ModelMap model) {
  model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
  model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
  model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());
  return "result";
}
```

this is web.xml

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HelloWeb</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

this is HelloWeb-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="nil" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am not wrong,

the URL which you are giving is

```
url: '/addStudent.htm' ,
```

Please add the context path in the URL

```
url : '<contextPath>/addStudent.htm'
```

ContextPath usually would be the name of your war file. Try and let know

Comment: i have try that also bt still it is giving me same error my war file name is HelloWeb ...so i tried url:'HelloWeb//addStudent.htm'and also url:'/HelloWeb//addStudent.htm'and